# is there any way to search through cs file

Tags: .net, reflection, c#-3.0, reflection.emit, system.reflection

I have a requirement to list out the methods in the cs files and list the each method call inside a method .
For example : i have a class

```
public void method1 ()
{
    c2.M2();
}

public void method2 ()
{
    c2.m3();
}
```

Here c2 is another class and m2 m3 are the methods of that class. Here i need to prepare a list c2.m2(), and c2.m3() , i have one hundred or more cs files to list out these details.

Is there any way i can effectively navigate through cs files and search instead of loading them and dealing with file stream readers?

Comment: Check out the System.Reflection namespace.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens , may be i did not framed my question properly , through reflection we can list the methods in the class but not the method body content, i am trying to list the method calls inside a method

Comment: can somebody answer this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different ways of getting what you're looking for:

- [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) looks at compiled assemblies (like Reflection and/or ILDasm) and lets you inspect the IL instructions inside method bodies.
- [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) looks at .cs source files and gives you a parse tree.

Either one should let you list the calls made inside each method.

Comment: Hi , Using Mono.Cecil it is of licensed version and has to be purchased , even i have tried with the sample code i was able to extract the c# format of a method but not the list of method calls inside a method, if i had to extract a method code i can use this one but unfortunately i have cs files need to list out the method calls. If you have a sample code of listing a methods inside a method using Cecil will be very helpful

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea that Mono.Cecil needs to be purchased -- it's open-source (their Web site doesn't seem to mention the license, but you can see it in the [license header](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil/ArrayType.cs) in the source files; it's the [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)). As for how to use Cecil, try starting with the [Cecil FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil:FAQ) and the [`mono.cecil` tag on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mono.cecil).

Comment: Sorry i was misunderstood the tools between Reflector and Mono.cecil,thanks for your reply and i have seen the code but not found any useful for my requirement i needed to list out the methods called inside the methods in the classes but by this Mono.cecil i could able to extract the instructions. please provide some help. Can i get any help with the Nunit framework ?..

Comment: The Cecil FAQ tells you two different ways to get the instructions inside a method body. From there it should be a matter of looking for `call` and `callvirt` instructions (and possibly `newobj` or a few others, depending on your requirements). What have you tried, and what are the specific problems you're running into?

Comment: I have tried this Cecil faq only but instructions are in the format of Opcodes and values are in integers it is quite confusing. how to get the c# format of instructions oras you have mentioned call and callvirt instructions has to be separated how to do that . a simple example can help me .

Comment: Roslyn is not avaialable for VS 2010 .

Comment: and cecil will have OpCodes and instructions as a format. both are not helpful in my case Can anyone help me on this .?